# Spel and PreAuthorize: extracting property from list argument

Tags: spring-security, spring-el

I have my own permissionEvaluator with takes `List<Long> ids` as parameter and is able to preAuthorize such case for example:

```
  @PreAuthorize("isUserAssignedToDepartment(#case.departmentId)")
  public void storeCase(Case case);
```

And I have dozens of different operations to secure including list of objects in parameter but all of those objects have `departmentId`. The question is how to map those objects to collection od ids that i need ?

The hardest one would be something like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("isUserAssignedToDepartment(#xObjects.stream().map(XObjects::getDepartmentId).collect(Collectors.toSet()))")
      public void migrateXObjects(List<XObjects> xObjects, boolean sendEmails);
```

My `isUserAssignedToDepartment` evaluator could take a list of ids but the above example throws `spel` exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException:
> Expression
> [#oauth2.throwOnError(isUserAssignedToDepartment(#xObjects.stream().map(XObjects::getDepartmentId).collect(Collectors.toSet())))]
> @200: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was
> 'colon(:)'

I see some spell projections that are able to map one collection to another:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-projection

```
// returns ['Smiljan', 'Idvor' ]
List placesOfBirth = (List)parser.parseExpression("Members.![placeOfBirth.city]");
```

But would it be possible to combine PreAuthorize with it somehow ? My method has two parameters:

```
@PreAuthorize("isUserAssignedToDepartment(#xObjects.stream().map(XObjects::getDepartmentId).collect(Collectors.toSet()))")
          public void migrateXObjects(List<XObjects> xObjects, boolean sendEmail);
```

My permission evaluator:

```
public class UserAssignedToDepartmentimplementsEvaluator TargetedPermissionEvaluator {

    @Getter
    private final String name;
    private final SomeService someService; 

    public UserAssignedToDepartmentimplementsEvaluator (String name,
                                                                   SomeService someService) {
        this.name = name;
        this.someService= someService;
 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object o, Object o1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable id (or list of ids), String targetType, Object permission) {
        if (id == null) {
            log.warn("id is null!");
            return false;
        }
(...) // do business checks..
}
```